# Git not getting write access

Tags: windows, git, github

I have recently bought a Windows 8 machine and I'm attempting to install Git. I *think* I have it all working correctly (I have done this correctly a few ties before). However, when I try to clone one of my repos from Github, I get the following error.

`fatal: could not create work tree dir '..': Permission Denied`

I am trying to do this inside C:\inetpub\wwwroot, would this be a windows "sensitive information" folder? In which case, how do I let it be edited by programs? (If that's what it's even called)

Or, if I only need to run this in administrator mode, how would I be able to do this when I right click in the folder and select "Git Bash Here" ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`Disable UAC`, make sure that you are logged in as `full Administrator` and run `Git` as `Administrator` too.